# Why I got content-type text/html instead of application/json in rest api java after deployed on server?

Tags: java, rest, content-type

> This is the result of my local project.
>
> - Vary: Origin Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method Vary:
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers Content-Type: application/json
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Thu, 08 Oct 2020 15:51:02 GMT
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=60`` Connection: keep-alive

---

> This is the result of remote server.
>
> - We are completely uploaded and fine < HTTP/1.1 404  < Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 < Content-Language: en < Content-Length: 776 <
>   Date: Thu, 08 Oct 2020 15:46:43 GMT

Comment: Please include relevant information in text format in your question. On stack overflow, people don't like to read screenshots.

Comment: You marked the relevant part yourself bold. You're getting a default 404 response because the resource you request is not found. That response is returned as text/html. But we cannot tell what the problem is without any context or more information.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, there are more differences. The most important difference is the HTTP status code. I can't see it from your local project, but from the tomcat server you get a status 404: Not Found.

So you either didn't deploy your application correct, you made a typo in the URL, or something inside your application decided to return a 404.

Hard to say which is the problem based on your input so far. Do you have logs from the tomcat server?